# Python3 read args from file in Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, args

I have program.py that accepts only one argument as URL:

```
python3 program.py http://www.xxx.xxx
```

and the code is something like this

```
def Video(url)
    #do something
    #with that url string

def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("url", help="Add URL", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()  
    Video(args.url) # here most the list of urls from file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

But I would like my program to read the URL from a file, one after the other has ended

Something like this:

```
Python3 program.py < URLfile
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('url', nargs='+', type=str)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    for x in args['url']:
        Video(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

and to use it:

```
 python3 program.py  $(<links)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
for url in sys.stdin.readlines():
    do_something(url.strip())
```

Comment: I would like to be more than one line of text in the URLfile,

Comment: yep just saw that and changed my response

Answer (score 0):

I think [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is what you need.
Flexible format:

```
[DEFAULT]
ServerAliveInterval = 45
Compression = yes
CompressionLevel = 9
ForwardX11 = yes

[bitbucket.org]
User = hg
```